# jQuery serialize without name?

Tags: jquery, serialization

Using .serialize(), I just want an array of the values not the name value pair.

For example, return this:

> Single&Multiple&Multiple3&check2&radio1

Instead of:

> single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1

Comment: I'm curious about why you want that?

Comment: Mentioned this below, but what I am trying to do is build a string from user-selected items on a form so that I can write it to a url like so:
value1/value2/value3/value4

Comment: This is dangerous, because you have to be sure about the exact order. And that not a single value is in between that should bot be there. You better show the form and the url you want to have out of that

Comment: Good point Yunzen. Do you have a suggestion. I am surprised that I can't find a jQuery method to do this -- just give you a list of form values selected by the user.

Comment: If you look at typo3 realURL externsion you will see, that even when you have a url like you want, it is type of /name1/value1/name2/value2

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to transform the appropriate `input`s (in this example, all `input`s, `select`s, `textarea`s that aren't buttons) into an array of their values, then use `join`:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function (e) {
    var serialized = 
        $(":input:not(:button, :submit)", this).map(function(i, el) {
            return el.value;
        }).get().join("&");

    alert(serialized);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/zQ4P2/1/

Comment: I am trying to do this with serialize because that will give me only user-defined form values (checked radios, selected selects, etc). The function that you wrote includes every input on the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own plugin to do that:

```
jQuery.fn.mySerialize = function() {

  var returning = '';

  $('input, select, textarea', this).each(function() {
      if (this.value !== "") // check this to avoid && in returning string
          returning += '&' + this.value;
  });

  return returning.substring(1);

};
```

And you can use it like so:

```
var serialize = $("form#fID").mySerialize();
alert(serialize);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/n2tca/

Comment: I am trying to do this with serialize because that will give me only user-defined form values (checked radios, selected selects, etc). The function that you wrote includes every input on the form.

Comment: Is there a way to target user defined selections?

Fields that have been filled out, Selected radios, Checked checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of defeating the purpose of serialize, but you could build your own:

```
var serializeValues = function(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for(x in obj) result.push(obj[x]);
  return result.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $("form").serialize();
var newValue = value.replace(/&[^=]+/g, "").replace(/=/g, "/");
```

String.replace: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

JS Regex:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: My regex /.*=/ might be greedy, and take up a lot. Sorry haven't had a chance to test it.

Comment: @micha Can you explain the regex you added?

Comment: Hmmm, this gives me the list of names but not values.

Comment: Got it to work on value only by doing this:

formString.replace(/&[^=]+/g, "").replace(/=/g, "/");

Comment: sorry I've changed the question in my head