# name attribute self references id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In short, is there some self reference code to set the name attribute equal to the id?
for example,

```
<input name="this.id" id="input1">
```

In long, using `.serialize()` requires use of the `name` attribute. Hypothetically, there is a form that contains many inputs without `name` attributes. I'm aware of,

- how I could (read, "should") add `name` attributes that match the `id`'s to each input,
- [creating a separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740730/jquery-serialize-without-name) to serialize the form using `id` attribute,
- similar solution like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472706/modify-serialize-form-function-to-take-input-id-instead-of-name),
- the steps taken to [submit a form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

However, in some research on SO, I was led to believe that if a person were to use,

```
<input name="id[]" id="input1">
```

when serialized, the `name` would have the `id` appended to it. In my tests this method produces id%5B%5D (url encoded string of id[]). Using anything available, is there a short hand way to set the `name` attribute so that it references the `id` attribute on each input?

Comment: So why don't you either set the name when you create the form or run code to set the name of the inputs

Comment: In actuality, that is probably what I will do. Curiosity drives this query.

Comment: How are all these inputs created in the first place? Seems like starting where they get generated would make sense

Comment: There is nothing in HTML to set the name to reference the id....

Comment: @charlietfl Someone else created them. You're right.

Comment: In JavaScript `inputElement.name = inputElement.id`, would assign the id to the name.

Comment: @PHPglue That would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in HTML that will do the reference so you will need to set it manually. The best solution, set it when you build the form. Or set it when you reference the elements

```js
console.log($("input").attr("name", function (){ return this.name || this.id }).serialize())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo1" value="1" />
<input id="foo2" value="2" />
<input id="foo3" value="3" />
<input id="foo4" value="4" />
```

or just write your own method

```js
$.fn.serializeId = function() {
  return $(this).map(function(){
    return this.id + "=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val())
  }).get().join("&");
}


console.log($("input").serializeId())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo1" value="1" />
<input id="foo2" value="2" />
<input id="foo3" value="3" />
<input id="foo4" value="4" />
```

Comment: This is a solution, possibly the shortest route to the desired end. However, I'm much more curious for other ways to do what I've asked.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. The two solutions are either you set it or write your own serialize.

Comment: Not possible _yet_.